# Javascript Setter is not a function error

Tags: javascript, class, setter

When I tried to log the isCheckedOut setter on the console,  I am getting an error testLib.isCheckedOut is not a function

I'm having a hard time figuring out why. Any help would be very great

```
            /* Parent Class */
class Library {
  constructor(title) {
    this._title = title;
    this._isCheckedOut = false;
    this._ratings = [];
  }

  get title() {
    return this._title;
  }

  get isCheckedOut() {
    return this._isCheckedOut;
  }

  set isCheckedOut(value) {
    this._isCheckedOut = value;
  }

  get ratings() {
    return this._ratings;
  }

  getAverageRating() {

  }

  toggleCheckOutStatus() {

  }

  addRating() {

  }
}

const testLib = new Library;
console.log(testLib.isCheckedOut(true));
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)? Setters are not called like functions.

Answer (score 2):

Setters *obfuscate* the fact that they're functions to callers. When you have an object with a setter, to invoke the setter, assign to the property:

```
someObj.theSetterPropertyName = theArgumentToPassToSetter;
```

Similarly, to invoke a getter, reference the property as an expression:

```
someObj.theGetterPropertyName
```

So, you want:

```js
class Library {
  constructor(title) {
    this._title = title;
    this._isCheckedOut = false;
    this._ratings = [];
  }

  get title() {
    return this._title;
  }

  get isCheckedOut() {
    return this._isCheckedOut;
  }

  set isCheckedOut(value) {
    this._isCheckedOut = value;
  }

  get ratings() {
    return this._ratings;
  }
}

const testLib = new Library;
testLib.isCheckedOut = true; // invoke setter
console.log(testLib.isCheckedOut); // invoke getter
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const testLib = new Library;
console.log(testLib.isCheckedOut = true);
```

[JS setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

> The set syntax binds an object property to a function to be called when there is an attempt to set that property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call setter like function.

> a setter can be used to **execute a function** whenever a specified property
> is attempted to be changed

Set a property using a setter:

```
const testLib = new Library;
testLib.isCheckedOut = true;
console.log(testLib.isCheckedOut);
```

Calling a function:

```
const testLib = new Library;
testLib.addRating();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue at this lesson, only used empty brackets instead of `.isCheckedOut(true)`. Got the same error.

```js
console.log(testLib.isCheckedOut(true));
```

Remove the brackets altogether after the isCheckedOut property and it'll work:

```js
console.log(testLib.isCheckedOut);
```